# How to get group/channel listing from applozic

Tags: android, applozic

I am creating a group chat & able to create groups, but I  can't find any reference to retrieve the group lists from applozic.

Comment: You can check how they have implemented the same in their sample app. 
You can get a reference in this file https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK/blob/master/mobicomkitui/src/main/java/com/applozic/mobicomkit/uiwidgets/people/channel/ChannelFragment.java You can use the same for your project.

Comment: Yes, that's how they doing this using local db, 

Channel channel = ChannelDatabaseService.getInstance(getContext()).getChannel(cursor);

I want to know the API service, from where I can fetch the group listing directly from the backend.

API for fetching the groups.

Comment: I think they have this in their documentation. You could've easily found it here https://docs.applozic.com/v1.0/reference#users-group-list